# How can we make this function calculate the number of days between two entered dates excluding weekends and holidays?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm actually working on a Leave Management System with php that requires to calculate the number of days between two entered dates which are the starting day and the end day of the leave (input dates on a webpage) excluding weekends and some specific holidays.

Here's the function I made:

```js
function calc_days() {
    var days = 0;
    if ($('#date_start').val() != '') {
        var start = new Date($('#date_start').val());
        var end = new Date($('#date_end').val());
        
        var currentDate = new Date(start);
        while (currentDate <= end) {
        var dayOfWeek = currentDate.getDay();
        if (dayOfWeek !== 0 && dayOfWeek !== 6) { // Exclude weekends
            var isHoliday = false;
            var month = currentDate.getMonth();
            var day = currentDate.getDate();
            if (month === 0 && day === 1) { // Jour de l'an
            isHoliday = true;
            } else if (month === 0 && day === 11) { // Manifeste de l'indépendance
            isHoliday = true;
            } else if (month === 4 && day === 1) { // Fête du travail
            isHoliday = true;
            } else if (month === 7 && (day === 14 || day === 20 || day === 21)) { // Fêtes de la révolution du roi et du peuple et de la jeunesse
            isHoliday = true;
            } else if (month === 8 && day === 1) { // Fête de la marche verte
            isHoliday = true;
            } else if (month === 11 && day === 18) { // Fête de l'indépendance
            isHoliday = true;
            }
            if (!isHoliday) {
            days++;
            }
        }
        currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
        }
    }
    if ($('#type').val() == 2) {
        $('#leave_days').val('.5');
    } else {
        $('#leave_days').val(days + 1);
    }
    }
```

The code works correctly only when the amount of days selected is over a week, otherwise it returns values more than expected when I choose less than 7 days.

**Examples:**

when I choose 16/03/2023 as a start date and 16/03/2023 as an end day, it returns 2 days instead of 1.

if i chose 16/03/2023 as a start date and 17/03/2023 it returns 3 days... etc.

but when I chose 7 days or more like 16/03/2023 and 23/03/2023 it works correctly

Comment: How this question is PHP related?

Comment: @YourCommonSense this script is on a php file and uses php variables

Comment: There's no sign of that here, so I'd guess it's not relevant to the problem at hand

Comment: @ADyson when I try the code it gives an incorrect number

Comment: Yes you said that in the question  already. Can you provide a specific example of input values you used, the output you received, and the output you expected instead?

Comment: The code works correctly only when the amount of days selected is over a week, otherwise it returns values more than expected when I choose less than 7 days.

Comment: It's ok you can stop repeating yourself! If you have more information thought, please [edit] the question (as I did with your previous comment) rather than hiding it down here! Thanks. If I have time later I will look in detail at the issue, or someone else may see it in the meantime.

Comment: Text that people can directly re-use in examples, demos etc is better than pictures of text that they have to then copy out again. So I rolled back your edit. By all means use pictures _as well as_ the text data, to illustrate your point, but don't use pictures _instead of_ text. See also [Why not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Thanks.

Comment: Well it was a screenshot of dates examples i chose and the result i got, not code or text that needs to be copied by anyone

Comment: Really? you must realise that people will want to re-use your test data when they try to reproduce and fix the errors, when they are trying to answer your question...and they don't want to type the data again by hand, they want to just copy it, because that's much easier, and there is no danger of typos. And in this case I don't think a picture of some textboxes containing data really provides any more context than the text examples of the data itself, anyway. Read the link I gave above, if you need more understanding.